# creating a dataframe from contents of multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, file, directory

We need to write a program that can access all the files in a given folder. Each file contains a single line string and we need to store the file name as well as the content of the file in a dataframe and return the csv file. 
how to solve this question ?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning`, `operating-system`, or `jupyter` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't clearly state, what file you would like to open, so assumed it is a .txt file. You can use `os.listdir(path)` to get a list of all files stored at a certain path. Then load the text files and append the content and the filename in a list. Finally, create a DataFrame and save to csv.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# set the path to your file location
path = r'path\to\Text'
# create a empty list, where you store the content
list_of_text = []

# loop over the files in the folder
for file in os.listdir(path):
    # open the file
    with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as f:
        text = f.read()
    # append the text and filename
    list_of_text.append((text, file))

# create a dataframe and save
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_text, columns = ['Text', 'Filename'])
df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, 'new_csv_file.csv'))
```